# CPU fan surges frequently

Tags: cpu, motherboard, fan, cooling, temperature

I have an AMD A8-3870 in a Gigabyte GA-A75M board. The CPU fan frequently spins up and down, based on load. Recently it's MUCH more noticeable.  The processor seems to run at an acceptable temp using Open Hardware Monitor (30C, spiking at 52C) where max temp is 72.7C. It doesn't take much for the fan to spin up now.

I've cleaned dust out of the case, taken then cpu fan/heatsink off, blown it out, applied new thermal paste. Still having issues.

The noise is my concern. It doesn't sound like a bearing or anything, it's just noisy spinning up and down. My question is, am I dealing with the fan going out or is there something causing undue load on the processor, causing the fan to spin up?

Comment: Monitor your cpu load using task manager

Comment: It could be just a noisy fan. My fan spins up at 30 - 50% CPU load but it remains quite quiet.

Comment: You sure there isn't any malware?

Comment: You can test for malware by making a Linux LiveUSB and booting from that, which quickly eliminates the possibility of any Windows malware causing such a problem. Download Lubuntu 19.10 @ https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours Check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 . Make a Linux LiveUSB following these instructions on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 then reboot the PC, choose the LiveUSB from yr Boot Manager after POST completes, & run Lubuntu apps to test for fan run up/down.

Comment: @Moab I've been watching for a while using Sysinternals ProcessExplorer. I don't see anything that is very obvious. It will spin up at 70% 'System Idle'.

Comment: @Phoenix I'm using Windows Security along with SUPER Antispyware. Everything is clean according to those.

Answer (score 0):

If the fan spins AND it moves air, it's just a noise issue.

However, a failing bearing (especially if it is a sleeve bearing) could cause noise AND reduce the air volume moved by the fan. I would shop for a replacement heatsink/fan assembly which has a low noise rating.

Since that CPU is a nine year old design, if it's the original heatsink/fan assembly, it may be heatsink fan replacement time.

Discussion and recommendations of specific quiet heatsinks/fan assemblies to fit the FM1 socket 100W TDP [AMD A8-3870K CPU](https://www.amd.com/en/support/apu/amd-series-processors/amd-a8-series-apu-for-desktops/a8-3870k-radeon-hd-6550d) would be the province of https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com, but tech support inquiries such as this are very on-topic and acceptable here.

Comment: Since it's acceptable, is there a fan/heat sink anyone would recommend?

Comment: Recomendations of specific quiet heatsinks/fan assemblies to fit the FM1 socket 100W TDP AMD A8-3870K CPU would be the province of https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com, However, with a nine-year-old design, I will suggest not spending much as replacing the entire motherboard-CPU-heatsink-RAM, if you have a desktop, is pretty cheap these days (for values of cheap).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep on using the computer, please do something about fixing the noisy fan. I always replace a noisy fan for two reasons.

1. I don't like noisy fans.
2. A noisy fan will typically work at half or less than its normal speed, which can cause the computer to overheat and its hardware components to wear out faster.